# Input parameter for report in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services

```
WHERE      ((100 * FreeSpace / Capacity) <= 20),               -- error on this comma
           SystemName = @p_ServerName
```

Does anyone know what could cause the error? And if the code is the right way to do what I am trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't the comma be an `AND`?

```
WHERE ((100 * FreeSpace / Capacity) <= 20) AND SystemName = @p_ServerName
```